# indexing table row by row in solr

Tags: mysql, solr, lucene, dih

i'm kinda new to **Solr** and i'm trying to index around 1M  tweets in solr  in order to be able to search them afterwards

i have those tweets in a **MYSQL** database 
i know how to index separate files in Solr , but actually i can't divide the tweets into 1M files

so i'm asking if there's a way to index sql table in solr row by row

what i've tried to far :

- indexing separate xml file in Solr
- i knew it could be handled from [DataImportHandler](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler) but am little confused with the tutorial

Comment: Confused about what? What error do you get when you try to use DIH? (DIH is the suggested way to do this). You can also have several documents (tweets) in one XML file, if you still want to index by file.

Comment: i didn't know where to find the Solr config and the Data-config then i 
i've found a DIH example in directories of solr , contains an example to it . much thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track, using the Data Import Handler (DIH) is a good place to start. Did you see the link to the [DIH Quick Start](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DIHQuickStart) on the DataImportHandler wiki page. For your given use case this should be pretty close to what you need.

In order to run the DIH examples that come with solr in the /example/example-DIH folder you will need to start Solr using the last example listed below in the excerpt from the Readme.txt file:

> By default, start.jar starts Solr in Jetty using the default solr home
>   directory of "./solr/" -- To run other example configurations, you can
>   speciy the solr.solr.home system property when starting jetty...
>
> java -Dsolr.solr.home=multicore -jar start.jar
>
> java -Dsolr.solr.home=example-DIH -jar start.jar

Comment: i've made the tutorial line by line , actually used the built folder by solr for dataimport . but whenever i click http://localhost:8983/solr/db/dataimport 

it gives me Error 404 Problem accessing /solr/db/dataimport. Reason:
    NOT_FOUND

Comment: See updated answer for how to start Solr configured to use the example-DIH example configurations.